# rendering a partial with camping and haml

Tags: ruby, haml, camping

I'm trying to make a simple blog with camping, like the example that comes with camping, only I want to use haml for the views instead of markaby. I want to render the posts using a _post.html.haml partial, but I have a feeling I may be going about it the wrong way.

Blog.rb

```
require 'camping'

Camping.goes :Blog

Blogtitle = "My Blog"

module Blog
  # Path to where you want to store the templates
  set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/views'
  module Blog::Models
    class Post < Base; belongs_to :user; end
    class Comment < Base; belongs_to :user; end
    class User < Base; end
  end

  module Blog::Controllers
    class Index
      def get
        @posts = Post.find :all
        render :index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

views/index.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
%head
%meta{'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type', :content => 'text/html', :charset => 'UTF-8' }/
%title=Blogtitle
%body=render @posts
```

views/_post.html.haml

```
%h2=post.title
%p=post.html_body
```

error

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `to_sym' for #<Array:0xb6e426d4>

Ruby  (eval): in lookup, line 12
Web  GET 0.0.0.0/

Traceback (innermost first)

(eval): in lookup
(eval): in render
/home/tony/src/blog/views/index.html.haml: in evaluate_source
%body=render @posts
```

Comment: The `meta` tag is already in the list of [self-closing tags](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#selfclosing_tags_), so you don't need the trailing `/`; if you remove that, does it help?

Comment: No, the issue is with the `%body=render @posts` line, but thanks, I didn't know that the `/` was unnecessary..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, to render a partial, you'll have to do something like this:

```
render :_post, :locals => { :post => post }
```

If you wish to render all the posts, just use a loop:

```
%body
  - @posts.each do |post|
    = render :_post, :locals => { :post => post }
```

Comment: Awesome! That works great. I didn't know about the `:locals` parameter...guess I should have read this?? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html

Comment: It's unfortunately not documented yet, but http://camping.rubyforge.org/api.html#M000006 is where it should be. The fact that `:locals` also works in Rails is more like a coincident. Don't expect the other options to work :-)